# Python BeautifulSoup html.parser not working

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a script to pull off book information from Amazon which was running successfully before but failed today. I am not able to figure out exactly what is going wrong but I am assuming its the parser or Javascript related. I am using the below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=9780307397980',headers={'User-Agent': b'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'})
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
resultcol = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'resultsCol'})
```

Previously I used to get data in `resultcol` but now its blank. When I check `html` I see the tag i am looking for i.e. `<div id="resultsCol" class=\'\' >`. But `soup` does not have this text in it. Can anyone help me debug this? It was working perfectly fine before but now it is not.

Comment: That's odd! I ran this code, but I left out the headers because It's been a while since I used requests and I don't remember all the specifications. Everything seemed to be working fine! Maybe try running it without passing the headers kwarg? There could be some error with your header.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Headers seem to be fine. I am getting the correct information in the 'html' element. 'soup' is not catching all the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the page is completely loaded. You have to use `phantomJs` to make sure page is loaded correctly.

I was able to get the correct element with following code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = ("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3D"
       "stripbooks&field-keywords=9780307397980")

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
resultcol = soup.find('img', attrs={'class': 's-access-image'})
print resultcol
```

Comment: The result through this method is not the same I get to view in the `view-source` of chrome that I see.

The other part of my script needs to find a link ending with `keywords=9780307397980` 

        `for url in resultcol.find_all('a'):
            if url['href'].endswith('keywords='+str(ISBN_search)):
                if 'dp' in url['href']: 
                    sub_link.append(url['href'])
                    linklist[link_search - 1] = url['href']
                    break`

Comment: @NeilS You can refine the element searching here.

Comment: I am not able to located the URL containing the element. I can see it on Chrome but not in `soup`

Comment: @NeilS check the updated code for your required element. You will need a regex to fetch the URL.

Comment: I am sorry if I wasnt clear before, but I am looking for this link in the script: `https://www.amazon.com/Year-Flood-MaddAddam-Trilogy/dp/030739798X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1536785536&amp;sr=8-1&amp;keywords=9780307397980`.... If you open the link `https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=9780307397980` on chrome and view the source code (ctrl+u) and go to line 1419 (dont know it would be same for you), I can see this link. In `soup` that we just parsed, I cannot see this part. Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 1):

Remove headers, and it should work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-    alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=9780307397980')
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
resultcol = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'resultsCol'})`
```

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'parser'`

Comment: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo' - This usually happens because you called find() and then tried to access the .foo` attribute of the result. But in your case, find() didn’t find anything, so it returned None, instead of returning a tag or a string. You need to figure out why your find() call isn’t returning anything." from BS4 Documentation

Comment: I think the problem is with 'div'